# Как реализовать передачу данных из js в action yii2?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

Есть задача: реализовать некоторое подобие метрики\аналитики посетителей сайта.

Как сделано сейчас:
REST api
При заходе на index выполняется actionCreate, создаём новый объект типа Visitor, при создании заполняем его свойства ip, user agent и т.д., затем отправляем это всё в бд.

Как хочется сделать:
при загрузке при загрузке страницы, некоторый js файл получает клиентские данные (ip, user agent и т.д.) и передаёт их в actionCreate (название экшена условно), который в свою очередь отправляет полученные данные в бд.

В чём вопрос:
как реализовать правильно передачу необходимых данных, и вообще рабочая ли схема получится (при условии, что у клиента включены js конечно)?

Comment: В целом можно реализовать (ajax'ом отправлять GET-запрос на конкретный экшен), только вот пока не пойму в чем преимущество именно такого подхода, если в итоге получается то же самое? Или суть в том что данный скрипт может работать на совершенно разных порталах, а где-то будет сайт-агрегатор (с этим экшеном create)? Ну и насчет IP - это уже нужно будет получать на стороне сервера, я думаю.

Comment: @AlexNem, если я правильно понимаю, преимущество такого подхода в том, что с помощью js можно получить больше информации о посетителе, а значит точнее идентифицировать его. И да, в дальнейшем планируется интеграция скрипта на несколько сайтов, с которых необходимо получать информацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить данные о клиенте (браузер, ОС, прочее) можно в JavaScript при помощи

```
window.navigator
```

navigator это объект содержащий поля с необходимой вам информацией. Например, вот так можно получить строку с информацией об ОС.

```
var os = window.navigator.oscpu
```

Вот так о браузере

```
var browser = window.navigator.appCodeName
```

Более подробно о том, какие поля содержатся в этом объекте можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript), либо просто выведите объект в консоль - `console.log(window.navigator)`

Вы можете получить необходимые поля как строки, а затем выполнить AJAX-GET запрос по указанному адресу. Если вам нужен именно чистый JavaScript, без jQuery, то это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
var os = window.navigator.oscpu
var browser = window.navigator.appCodeName

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "путь-к-екшену?os="+os+"&browser="+browser, true);
ajax.send();

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        //Здесь обработка ответа
    }
    else{
        //Здесь обработка ошибки
    }
};
```

Затем, уже в самом вашем екшене вы получите в качестве параметров переменные `os` и `browser`, и уже можете делать с ними что угодно. А вот IP получать нужно будет уже в самом екшене (обычным PHP-шным способом)

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезный ответ!  К примеру я передаю в экшн данные из js (исп. ajax), используя их создаю объект и сохраняю его в бд. Предположим, мне необходимо из этого объекта отдать несколько свойств массивом в js (к примеру, установить cookies). Если передаю просто строку, всё ок console.log обрабатывает это, но если передавать например return [model->token, $model->ip]; то скрипт падает в error. В чём может быть дело?

Comment: console.log(window.navigator); так же выдаёт ошибку 500

Comment: Забыл указать тип принимаемых данных, теперь всё стало ок. Спасибо ещё раз

Answer (score 0):

Если код полагает единоразовую запись о клиенте при загрузке страницы, то нету смысла выносить всё в JavaScript.

Если замысел другой, то возможно запихать данные клиента в сам `html`:

```
<input type="hidden" id="userIp" value="123.15">...
```

При отправке данных на сервер:

```
let ip = document.getElementById('userIp').value;
```

Совсем иной вариант - создание и регистрация скрипта `js` из-под фреймворка(код в шаблоне):

```
$userIp = '123.15';
$script = <<< JS
    function sendUserData() {
        console.log($userIp);
    }
JS;
$this->registerJs($script, yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Замысел немного другой: хочется отслеживать некоторые моменты поведения посетителей сайта, в том числе переходы к покупкам и подобную информацию. Сейчас просто при помощи ajax хочется пробрасывать данные в php

Comment: @IgorMitrofanov Гугл аналитика не подходит?

Comment: конечно подходит, но стоит задача написать своё для своих целей

Comment: @IgorMitrofanov В таком случае желаю Вам удачи)